# Does a slow Time Machine disk affect general Mac performance?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, filesystem

Say a Mac Pro tower has OS X + Apps installed on a blazing fast PCIe SSD. It also has Time Machine enabled on a slow 5400rpm mechanical drive. The TM drive is internal and connected at all times.

Will the relative slowness of the TM drive affect general performance when the Mac and its filesystem are being used strenuously? Are internally connected TM drives being being read/written to constantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would think that a slow Time Machine disk is not going to really affect the performance of your machine.

If you are using the 5400 RPM disk *only* for Time Machine, then the performance of that disk is *only* going to affect the speed that backups are made and recovered for the most part. It is true that when TM is running it is scanning your hard disk to determine what has changed, but you indicated that it is a PCIe connected SSD and thus I'd take a guess that you're probably not saturating that drive's performance most of the time. It does seem that TM runs at a lower priority and thus normal activity on the SSD is going to get precedence.

In general, the small slices that TM is going to steal from your SSD most likely aren't noticable and the slower performance of the 5400 RPM disk is isolated only to TM since you're not using it for anything else.

For some perspective, I have a 2008 MacPro3,1 with 1 SSD, 1 7200 and 2 5400 "green" drives in it and Time Machine goes out to a fairly slow ReadyNAS Duo on the network. When TM kicks off I can hear the drives in the MacPro chattering away, but I don't notice any slow down with what I'm doing since TM appears to be lower priority. However, attempting to go into TM to restore anything and it can be fairly abysmal. Fortunately, I rarely restore from backup :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why one would have anything to do with the other. Drives are not being constantly read from and written to unless something needs to do that. You can play a video game and once it's in RAM it'll stop reading the hard drive in many cases. A large movie on the other hand will constantly read from the hard drive. But even still, Time Machine and your external drive are separate from the other stuff your computer does. While yes, it'll take longer to backup and restore from it, that's the extent of the slowness you'll have from it.

Comment: The reason I suspect it would have frequent activity is that my understanding is that Time Machine does not work simply on a fixed schedule, but rather keeps track of full(ish) file history every time files are changed.

Comment: @xyz From my experience, Versions on the system's hard drive backs up file changes when a change happens while Time Machine runs hourly. If you have a problem, just leave time machine's drive unplugged until you want to do that day's backup.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Mac Pro 2008 running El Capitan and also experienced slow downs with Time Machine. The slow downs had nothing to do with hard drive speed. I had never used Time Machine until I downgraded from Snow Leopard to El Capitan. I made a mistake and let Time Machine try to back up all connected drives. (I have four internal hard drives, and two external backup drives were connected.) I trashed Time Machine’s backups and set it to back up only my primary drive. It finished the backup overnight, but my Mac was still slow when Time Machine was on. Turning Time Machine off returned my Mac to normal speeds. I spent much time troubleshooting this problem. Some blog comments indicated that 'bad' permissions could cause slow downs during backups. I had many customized file and folder permissions from my Snow Leopard days. I went back to default permissions on all files and folders on my primary hard drive, and that bumped up my Mac's speed while Time Machine ran, but not to normal speed.

My Mac Pro had 5 GB of RAM, which Apple says is enough for El Capitan. However, RAM is cheap, so I bumped it to 11 GB. This did nothing for the Time Machine problem. It did help with Canvas Draw because it keeps as many graphic elements in RAM as possible.

I gave up on continuous operation of Time Machine. I perform a clone backup daily and a Time Machine backup once a week. That has worked well. I’m retired, so a crash that causes one day of data loss isn’t a disaster. If you need continual backups, then I recommend more troubleshooting: Install your OS on an erased drive. Test some applications to get a feel for speed. Set up Time Machine and have it backup your drive. After that is done, use apps that create data such as a text editor, spreadsheet, iMovie, etc. See if your Mac's speed remains nearly the same while Time Machine backs up the new data. If there isn't a slow down, then something in your primary drive software is interacting with Time Machine to slow down your Mac. Trash your Time Machine preference file: com.apple.TimeMachine.plist in yourHardDrive/Library/Preferences. It's unlikely to help, but it's easy. If that doesn’t help, then fixing the problem is hard. This isn't like the good old days with Conflict Catcher. The only approach I know is a clean install followed by installing other apps one at a time until the one that contributes to the Time Machine slow downs is identified. This will take many hours. An alternative is to download demos of third party programs that offer continual backupa.

If the newly installed OS and software also experiences a slow down when Time Machine runs, then you may have a hardware problem. Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks - You helped me realise that I don't particularly need "continuous" fine-grained backups and a full-drive snapshot on a fixed schedule is probably good enough.

Comment: I think El Capitan just seems to run slower on the 2008 MacPro3,1. I'm not sure if it is all the additional crap they added since Snow Leopard (10.8 seemed to be a bit of a sweet spot), but it could be that the code isn't profiled for the old Core 2 architecture anymore (though still binary compatible). I also somewhat suspect that memory compression utilizes things in the i5/i7 chips which wasn't there in Core 2 and the software compression default is several times slower.